# How to make application images on SD card not acessible for user?

Tags: android, image, download

I'm building app for downloading certain content (recipe) from my server, after they have code able to purchase it. So far I made this in my application:

- User downloads zipped file protected with password to SD card, so only application can extract it with password in code
- User with an event of button pressed unzips the file with password written in code and saves the recipes text to database

Problem occurs when I would like to extract images. It's not problem in extracting, but it's problem that user could access and have that pictures, once I extract them to SD card. Is there a way I could save images somehow on SD card so they're not accessible for user and protected so user can't delete them (so I don't need to check with application constantly application has all images to display) - I don't know how this would be possible, because theoretically in this case application could fill whole SD card and not allowing user to delete those pictures (maybe pictures can be somehow connected to application installation?). With textual representation of recipe there is no problem, since it's going straight to database, but I wouldn't like to save blob to database.

So, I hope you understand my problem. Can you tell me how to solve it and if maybe I'm on wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I could save images somehow on SD card so they're not accessible for user

No.

> and protected so user can't delete them

No.

> Can you tell me how to solve it and if maybe I'm on wrong track?

Keep the images on internal storage rather than external storage.

Comment: Thanks. So, I should first download zip file to external storage and then to unzip it and sort it out to internal storage?

Comment: @Tommz: That would be one approach, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`[1] and place your image files there.
Please be advised that your requirements are impossible to satisfy though. A couple of observations and suggestions regarding the `getExternalFilesDir` method:

> Is there a way I could save images somehow on SD card so they're not
>   accessible for user and protected so user can't delete them

Whatever is on the SD card will be accessible and can be deleted, be it on Android or if a user puts the SD card in a SD reader on a PC. If you want to protect your images from theft why decrypt them on the device? You could keep all the images encrypted and decrypt them on-the-fly in your application, for example by using a ContentProvider.

> so I don't need to check with application constantly application has
>   all images to display

But by all means you should! As I said, the user can always delete files from an SD or even from the application folder on internal memory (for example by pressing Clear Data in Settings->Apps). If you want the process to be as quick and easy as possible, you could have all your image data in a large blob file (optionally encrypted) and just check if it exists, has the right size (and optionally if it's up to date).

> theoretically in this case application could fill whole SD card and not
>   allowing user to delete those pictures (maybe pictures can be somehow
>   connected to application installation?

Yes! By using `Context.getExternalFilesDir` whatever you put in that folder will be counted as application data and can be cleared by the user. It will even be cleared when the application is uninstalled, which is nice since you don't want to leave megabytes and megabytes of unneeded files on the user's SD.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)